# How to read the file in order based on the number in the filename using glob?

Tags: python, csv, file, glob

I have to read the files in the folder using a loop for further action.

code format

```
for file in glob.glob('SZ*.csv'):
...     print(file)
```

Output I got

```
SZ1.CSV
SZ10.CSV
SZ11.CSV
SZ12.CSV
SZ13.CSV
SZ14.CSV
SZ15.CSV
SZ16.CSV
SZ17.CSV
SZ18.CSV
SZ19.CSV
SZ2.CSV
SZ20.CSV
SZ21.CSV
SZ22.CSV
SZ3.CSV
SZ4.CSV
SZ5.CSV
SZ6.CSV
SZ7.CSV
SZ8.CSV
SZ9.CSV
```

But I want to read the files in order based on the number in the filename.

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort it -

```
import re

sorted(glob.glob("SZ*.CSV"), key=lambda x: int(re.findall("[0-9]+", x)[0]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
import re

l = glob.glob('SZ*.CSV')
l.sort(key=lambda x: int(re.sub('[A-Z.]+', '', x)))
for file in l:
     print(file)
```